# Where was shutting up implicated, in Curran's reply to a hostile Lord Chancellor?

Tags: meaning-in-context, british-english

<sub>Source: p 56, *The Art of the Advocate* (1993) by [Richard Du Cann QC](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/people/obituary-richard-du-cann-1375068.html) (called to the Bar of England and Wales).</sub>

> It is these hidden qualities which, by their existence or their 
>   absence, make or mar the advocate. Some he must have, the 
>   possession of others, pleasing adjuncts to these essentials, permits 
>   him to stand above his fellows. He must have a good command of 
>   language. Words are his tools, and without them he will be lost. 
>   They must always be to hand. While in the middle of a long and 
>   involved review of political corruption in Ireland, Curran was 
>   unnecessarily interrupted by the hostile Lord Chancellor [hereafter LC] he was 
>   addressing. [[John Philpot] Curran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Philpot_Curran) replied:
>
> > I am aware My Lord, that truth is to be sought only by a slow and 
> >     painful process. I also know that error is, in its nature, flippant and 
> >     compendious. It hops with airy and fastidious levity over proofs and 
> >     arguments, and perches on assertion, which it calls conclusion.
>
> The Lord Chancellor did not interrupt again.

The author's comments imply not only efficacy but also disguised asperity in Curran's reply that succeeded in shutting up the LC. But what have I neglected, because to me Curran's reply appears too diplomatic and polite especially to a hostile LC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gracious, that is one of the *prettiest* smackdowns I have ever read.

Explaining it is going to be tricky.

The crucial thing to understand is that Curran doesn't tell the LC to shut up.  He made the LC look like an idiot, and the LC decided to shut up before he was made to look even more like an idiot.

When Curran refers to "error", mentally translate that as "being wrong", only with the implication of "being foolish".  Everything Curran attributes to "error", is a description of being not merely mistaken, but foolish: "flippant" has no positive valence, and "hops with airy and fastidious levity over proofs and arguments" (which: *wow!*) is a description of someone or something moving in a playful, unserious, even childish way (it makes one think of *skipping* like children do) that lacks all dignity and probity. It does this in disregard of important information – "perches on assertion, which it calls conclusion" – shooting its mouth off, uttering something that it calls a conclusion but which is only a baseless assertion.

Basically, he's saying, "well obviously anybody who is serious about getting to the truth of these matters will slog through all these tedious details with me; leaping to baseless so-called conclusions is something only a fool unconcerned with the truth would do."

And he manages to do all this, without actually saying any of these things *of the LC*. Part of why it's a gem of rhetoric is that he attributes these properties to "error", i.e. foolishness, itself, and thus insinuates the LC is making a fool of himself without having to call him one directly.

P.S. The word "perch" is the verb used to describe how *birds* rest.  In English, that birds are creatures of little intellect is encoded in our idiomatic insult "bird-brained".  Truly, this is insult raised to poetry.

Answer (score 1):

What looks like  politeness to you is smooth, brilliant, biting, and not quite understated satire. It is anything but diplomatic: look again  at the description in the last two sentences, which is  Curran's characterization of LC's remarks or comments or entire stance. No one in LC's position wants to be called out for being compendius or flippant, to be described as  one whose argument is airy, ignores proofs and arguments, and calls assertion  conclusion. You need to watch more *[Rumpole of the Bailey](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumpole_of_the_Bailey)* or *[Prime Minister's Questions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Minister%27s_Questions)* to get a handle on British understatement and satire.

Comment: Smooth, yes, brilliant, yes, biting, yes, but no, not satire.  It's definitely mockery, but not mockery by sarcasm or spoof (a kind of allusion to another work).  I'm pretty sure Curran earnestly and sincerely meant every acidic word he says.

Comment: Well I'm also sure Curran means every word. Maybe my understanding  of [satire](http://literaryterms.net/satire/) is off. I dunno. @Codeswitcher